# Como llamar a funcion AJAX desde otra tab?

Tags: php, javascript, json

Como hago para llamar a una funcion AJAX desde otra pagina , para que actualice un resultado.

Funcion en Pagina 2 , llame a funcion en pagina 1 y se ejecute cuando si es exitosa la carga del dato.

Es posible???

en pagina 1 se veria algo asi [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pagina 1 = Home.php

```
<script>function hayitemsnuevos()
var parametros = {
"inputitems" : $('#inputitems').val()
};
$.ajax({
data: parametros,
url:'buscasihayitemsnuevos.php',
type: 'post', 
dataType: 'json',
beforeSend: function () {},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
alert(xhr.statusText); 
alert(xhr.responseText); 
alert(thrownError); 
 } ,
success:  function (response) { 
$("#iconoitems").html(response.cantidaddeitemsnuevos);
},
})  </script>
```

Pagina 2=cargaitems.php

```
<script>function cargaitemsnuevos()
var parametros = {
"nuevoitem" : $('#nuevoitem').val()
};
$.ajax({
data: parametros,
url:'carganuevoitem.php',
type: 'post',
dataType: 'json',
beforeSend: function () {},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
alert(xhr.statusText);
alert(xhr.responseText);
alert(thrownError); 
} ,
success:  function (response) { 
 alert("Item Cargado correctamente!")
**hayitemsnuevos();**
 },
})  </script>
```

Comment: ¿A qué llamas *función json*?

Comment: la respuesta del ajax en formato json

Comment: No existen las funciones JSON,  porque no pueden existir funciones dentro de un verdadero formato JSON,  lo que si pueden existir es funciones en formato JSONP el cual es diferente a JSON.

Comment: No puedes ejecutar funciones de una página (cargada en un tab) desde otra página, simplemente porque el navegador no te lo va a permitir por razones de seguridad. Lo que vas a necesitar es una forma de *escuchar* los cambios producidos en el backend. Existen diversas formas de hacerlo, por ejemplo [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API), pero claro, eso significa que debes realizar los cambios apropiados tanto en backend como en frontend. Saludos

Comment: Amigo @leo en mi opinion es bueno escuchar a Mauricio Contreras, justo iba a comentar lo mismo, si deseas escuchar cambios en otra pagina debes usar tecnologias que lo permitan y que sean especializadas en ello (se llaman sockets), como socket.io o websockets, ambas son igual de buenas, sin embargo yo suelo usar socket.io.

Comment: @Riven estuve buscando ejemplos de   socket.io y websockets pero no encontre alguno que funcione sobre web en https , tenes idea de donde buscar un ejemplo simple que funcione? , mil gracias

Comment: Si que funcionan en https, pero sea que uses websockets o socket.io u algun otra tecnologia,  el hecho que funcionen en HTTPS tiene que ver es con que tu tienes que configurar unos certificados para poder usarlos en un entorno HTTPS,  igual sirve tambien para HTTP,  ademas debes tener en cuenta que si vas a usar cualquier tipo de sockets debes tener un socket cliente (javascript por ejemplo), y un socket servidor (nodejs o python por ejemplo), si no te funciona es porque no estas corriendo un servidor socket que escuche tus peticiones del cliente y las envie a otras partes.

Comment: Para http no hay que configurar certificados, pero la conexion sera insegura, aunque para pruebas es mas que suficiente usar HTTP,  luego en produccion te encargarias de los certificados.

Comment: @Riven Como ya el certificado SSL lo tengo contratado en el hosting , estoy buscando algun ejemplo para ver informacion REAL , pero ninguno esta bajo https  , hay 1 millon de chats y ninguno esta con certificado ( simplemente para ver como se hace  , despues cambiare el cerficado yo )

Answer (score 1):

Primero, no es función JSON, JSON es un tipo de formato para tratar los datos.

Para obtener un resultado como el de la imagen, tendrías que usar:

1. CSS para que el número de nuevos elementos se quede encima del icono o como quisieses.
2. En en el script de **home.php** usas AJAX llamando al archivo **buscasihayitemsnuevos.php**, que tendría que tener una consulta SQL que te devuelva el número de items nuevos, (ejemplo: 4).
3. En AJAX, cuando envías los datos en success, puedes tratar los datos que te ha devuelto **buscasihayitemsnuevos.php**.
4. Tu archivo **cargaitems.php** no te hace falta, porque con AJAX ya se carga el resultado en el div que le has indicado con el id.

De tal forma que el código sería algo así:

**home.php**:

Tendrás que usar un div (por ejemplo) para posteriormente mediante AJAX mostrar el número de items nuevos. Ese div junto con CSS se mostrará como en la imagen que has pasado.

```
<div id="iconoitems"></div>
```

**Script**:

```
function hayitemsnuevos()
 var parametros = {"inputitems" : $('#inputitems').val()};
 $.ajax({
  data: parametros,
  url:'buscasihayitemsnuevos.php',
  type: 'post', 
  dataType: 'json',
  beforeSend: function () {},
  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
   alert(xhr.statusText); 
   alert(xhr.responseText); 
   alert(thrownError); 
  } ,
  success:  function (response) { 
   $("#iconoitems").html(response.cantidaddeitemsnuevos);
  },
})
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: la funcion hayitemsnuevos(), se ejecuta inicialmente en la carga de la pagina , pero tambien necesito ejecutarla si y solo si hay items nuevos ( que se carga desde otra pagina ) ahi es cuando necesito que se ejecute hayitemsnuevos() , como la llamo desde otra pagina?

Comment: por qué hacerlo por separado cuando en success puedes comprobar si hay items nuevos o no (la consulta de devuelve 0 o > 0, es decir, hay items nuevos)?

Comment: Perdon , pero creo que no estoy siendo claro ( me disculpo si no fue asi ) , si en la pagina 2 , ejecute lo que ejecute NO VA A ACTUALIZAR el contenido de PAGINA 1 , es por eso que necesito el el success de pagina 2 , llamar la funcion de pagina 1  ( hayitemsnuevos() ) para que verifique y actulice el contenido,

Comment: Un ejemplo claro seria  , como te llego la notificacion que te respondi , cuando vos estas en otra pagina sin actulizar la misma.

Comment: si lo que necesitas es desde el success de página 2 llamar a hayitemsnuevos(), lo puedes hacer, es decir, puedes llamar a una función como si estuviese en el mismo archivo js, siempre que el archivo que contiene la definición de la función que vas a utilizar se haya cargado antes del usar esa función.